# Android: how to pass multiple values to setContentView() method from an activity class?

Tags: java, android, setcontentview

I have some problems passing and displaying values from the MainActivityClass to another MyActivityClass. So I learned here how to pass values from one class to another. Here's the method of MainActivity class which contains the intent to the other activtiy:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddAptActivity.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();

EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_address);
String message = editText.getText().toString();
EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
String message2 = editText2.getText().toString();

extras.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
extras.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE1, message2);

intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

and then in MyActivityClass receiving the values:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    String message = extras.getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String message2 = extras.getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE2);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    TextView textView2 = new TextView(this);
    textView2.setTextSize(40);
    textView2.setText(message2);

    setContentView(textView, textView2); 
}
```

but the setContentView() method doesn't want to accept more than one value. How can I display the other value in another textview and then display it???

I think I don't understand how to display values with setContentView... Please help me, as I am new in Android programming (just finished the 1st tutorial one week ago).

Comment: You can only add a view to your setContentView(...). Best create a new View that contains both TextView and then setContentView to this new View.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `ViewGroup` such as a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` then add TextViews to the same and then `setContenView(linearlayout);`

```
 LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this); 
 ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
 TextView textView = new TextView(this);
 TextView textView2 = new TextView(this);
 ll.addView(textView);
 ll.addView(textView2);
 setContenView(ll);
```

Answer (score 0):

setContentView() takes one Layout, either a View or a layout resource ID. You can pass in a LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc. to setContentView() which can contain any number of views. Probably a better approach would be to build a layout XML file that contains your view higherarchy then set it using setContentView(R.layout.someLayout);

see more info here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

You can only add a view to your setContentView(...). Best create a new View that contains both TextView and then setContentView to this new View.

```
RelativeLayout layout= new RelativeLayout(this);
layout.addView(textView1);
layout.addView(textView1);
setContentView(layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Several things wrong here so let's start from the beginning...

> but the setContentView() method doesn't want to accept more than one value. There is a method of it which takes a second param but that is for layout params.

Nope, if you look at [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28int%29) that's all it takes and you can't force it to take more (without rewriting the activity class).

> I think I don't understand how to display values with setContentView.

I don't think so either but you will.

You just set a `layout` (typically) with this method. You are creating `View`s dynamically which is ok but you don't need to. If you do then you need to add them to your inflated `layout` (the one you set in `setContentView()`). You can just add them to your layout (`someLayout.xml`) then get a reference to them

So it may look something like

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
/*
* call this first and it will save you some grief 
*/
where someLayoutFile is the xml file without the .xml extension
setContentView(R.layout.someLayoutFile);  

Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
String message = extras.getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
String message2 = extras.getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE2);

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.someID); // where someId is the id you give a TextVIew in your xml file
textView.setTextSize(40);
textView.setText(message);

// create another TextView in your xml and do the same with that using the appropriate layout
```

[See this page in the docs for more information](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

Comment: i think you need to change this `setContentView(textView, textView2);` and that is the reason for downvote i guess

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks for the catch! Got a phone call as I was answering :/

Comment: i too noticed it now as i was answering a different question and the downvote caught my attention